# Regular surfaces and geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

If F is a regular surface, $c: I \rightarrow F $ a geodesic and $\phi: J \rightarrow I$ a reparametrization, why does it hold that $c \circ \phi: J \rightarrow F$ is a geodesic if and only if $\phi(t) = mt + n$ for some $m, n \in \mathbb R$?

We had this theorem today in class, but unfortunately without any proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write down the definition of a geodesic, you'll see that a geodesic must have constant speed. That is, if $c \colon I \rightarrow F$ is a geodesic, we must have $ \left< c'(t), c'(t) \right> \equiv C$ for some $C \geq 0$ which is the speed of the geodesic. Thus, if $\phi \colon J \rightarrow I$ is a reparametrization and you want $c \circ \phi$ to be a geodesic, you must have

$$ \left< (c \circ \phi)'(t), (c \circ \phi)'(t) \right> = \left< c'(\phi(t)) \phi'(t), c'(\phi(t)) \phi'(t) \right> = (\phi'(t))^2 \left< c'(\phi(t)), c'(\phi(t) \right> \equiv D. $$

If $C = 0$ then $c$ is a constant curve and so **any** reparametrization of $c$ will also be constant and a geodesic. If $C > 0$, then we see that we must have $\phi'(t)^2 = \frac{D}{C}$ and since $\phi$ is regular ($\phi'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in J$), we must have

$$ \phi'(t) \equiv \sqrt{\frac{D}{C}} \implies \phi(t) = \sqrt{\frac{D}{C}}t + n $$

for some $n \in \mathbb{R}$ or

$$ \phi'(t) \equiv -\sqrt{\frac{D}{C}} \implies \phi(t) = -\sqrt{\frac{D}{C}}t + n $$

for some $n \in \mathbb{R}$.

The other direction can be checked directly using the definition of a geodesic.

Comment: Wow this is very good and answers my questions completely! :) Thank you very much! I didn't already accept this answer in order that you see my comment. Because of your answer, I've got a related question: Let's say we have a torus (obtained by rotating a circle), which latitudes on it are geodesics? I mean there are 3 possible candidates, aren't there? ( (a+r, 0), (a-r, 0), (a, r) )?

Comment: A latitude $v = v_0$ on a surface of revolution of the form $(\varphi(v) \cos(u), \varphi(v) \sin(u), \psi(v))$ will be a geodesic if and only if $\varphi'(v_0) = 0$ as can be seen by writing the geodesic equation. For the torus, this implies the only latitudes which are geodesics are the inner and outer equators (correspond to the circles obtained by  rotating the points $(a - r, 0, 0)$ and $(a + r, 0, 0)$ around the $z$ axis).

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent explanation! :)